# How to modify a specific element of a nested list using multilevel indexing in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to generate a square-like text structure in Python using nested lists. An array in which I could modify specific elements at specific indexes with a function like:

```py
def locate(self, x, y):
    return self.array[x][y]
```

The problem is that as I try to modify an element using multilevel list indexing, many elements are modified as well. Here's my code:

```py
length = 5

tip_row = list('+' * length)
mid_row = list('+' + ' '*(length-2) + '+')

array = [mid_row for _ in range(length-2)]
array.insert(0, tip_row)
array.append(tip_row)

array[3][3] = 'o'

for row in array:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

I expected the output to be:

```
+ + + + +
+       +
+   o   +
+       +
+ + + + +
```

But the actual output is:

```
+ + + + +
+   o   +
+   o   +
+   o   +
+ + + + +
```

Apparently, I cannot refer to a specific list in the array. Why is this happening?
How can I achieve the expected output?

Comment: You only have one ***o***, meaning you have 2 types of mid rows. But anyway, How would it look like for an even number (e.g. `length = 4`)?

Comment: take a look at [the python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types), and you can use `__getitem__` instead of locate. For the reason why all 3 middle rows are changed, you can check out [this talk](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#plummeting-cliff) which explains what variable names and references are. in short: `array = [mid_row for _ in range(length-2)]` copied the reference to `mid_row` 3 times, so all the middle rows point tot the same object

Comment: @MaartenFabré Thanks, your comment solved the problem. Instead of `array = [mid_row for _ in range(length-2)]`, I used `array = [list('+' + ' '*(length-2) + '+') for _ in range(length-2)]`. Same for `tip_row`. Works perfectly!

Comment: For your edit, the duplicates are right.  The problem is when you insert `mid_row` into your array, it only adds a pointer to the values of `mid_row` into your array.  So your array is:  `[ tip_row, mid_row, mid_row, mid_row, tip_row ]`.  When you change `array[3][3]` it changes the 4th element in `mid_row`.  So it changes them all!  Read on copy vs deep copy.  You want to copy the values, not just add a pointer to `mid_row`.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I'll remove the edit. Thanks and sorry for not realizing that before.